# Inconsistent search results for job alerts

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I found a bit of a strange bug with company job alerts and what jobs actually come back when you search with them.

I noticed this first with company you might have heard of, Stack Overflow. I clicked the "Create alert" button on the company page:

[image: Company Page - Create Job Alert]

I didn't think anything of it till I realised I didn't get any job alerts with the new jobs that were listed for Stack Overflow. Going back to the search page, I clicked the "Stack Overflow jobs" alert and was greeted with 0 results but there are currently 4 jobs listed (see first screenshot, next to "Create alert"):

[image: Job Search - No Results from Job Alert]

At this point, I'm thinking it might be a funny bug relating to a space in the company name. I found another company with a space in its name, created an alert the same way but both jobs they had available did come back:

[image: Job Search - 2 Results from Job Alert]

So now I'm thinking maybe its related to this second company having both their jobs listed as "Remote". I find that a little weird but at the same time, decided to check that too by finding another company.

Same process, created a job alert and clicked the link on the Job Search screen. This company has 3 jobs listed according to their company page and that's what the search results show too:

[image: Job Search - 3 Results which matches the Company Page]

Still not satisfied though as these were "Visa sponsor" and may be some sub-rule to how the alerts work, I went searching for another company.

I did find another company but this is where it gets even stranger for me. This company has 5 open jobs - 3 offer relocation + visa sponsorship and 2 don't.

I got 2 results back - the 2 that don't have relocation/visa sponsorship.

[image: Job Search - 2 Results which didn't match what I expected]

I thought maybe it was because it was "Featured" but other tests proved that not to be the case. I thought maybe it was experience or the technology but that didn't seem to lineup either.

Am I missing something or is there something kinda weird going on with the alerts and searching by them?

Comment: Not a full answer, but this has to do with advertising regions. On company pages, advertising regions are ignored (i.e. you can see all the jobs) but on job search they are enforced (i.e. you see only jobs that are advertised in your location). The GrubHub jobs that you can see in job search aren't affected because they target worldwide. I'll discuss the issue with the team.

Comment: Ahhhhh OK, I thought a job alert would be regardless of location unless I've specified it myself. To me, it kinda makes the "location" textbox a little redundant if by default "located anywhere" really means "located to where companies are targeting". I could see that maybe for "featured" jobs or maybe if it was just sorted differently because of regions but filtering out altogether seems odd to me.

Comment: @AurélienGasser, was there any outcome from your discussions with the team? Is this just by-design? Is it something that needs to be more obvious to the user? Is there a way for the user to get the alert regardless?

Comment: Yes, here's the outcome of the discussion: we're going to make the experience more consistent by filtering the jobs on company pages by advertising region, like on job search. It should be live in [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/234875). In order to get job alerts for jobs that are *not* advertised in your location, you can add locations you'd be willing to relocate to in your [job preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current)

Comment: @AurélienGasser, thanks for the info. It still seems a little strange that if I preference "remote" and a job offers remote that I'd need to add specific locations anyway. Is this mainly because "remote" might still mean "in the same timezone" rather than world-wide? I've added some locations to the page you linked me to just so I can get some alerts for particular businesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Aurélien pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368968/inconsistent-search-results-for-job-alerts#comment596973_368968), the problem is that we weren't respecting the advertising regions set by the employer on the Company Pages.

We've fixed it and it's live now, we're only showing the listings that apply to you on the company pages (as we do on the search results).

Thanks for the report!